# How to achieve zoom in effect like Apple News App or Pinterest ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, layer

Today I found out the the zoom in effect in Apple News App and Pinterest App and I wondered how I can achieve similar effect. I read about the blog of Pinterest https://engineering.pinterest.com/blog/behind-pins-building-pinterest-30-ios

and it says

> To do this, we used UINavigationControllerDelegate’s
>   animationControllerForOperation method to provide a
>   UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object to perform the transition

and I couldn't figure out what's behind the scene of `CBLPinViewTransition` of a type `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

It looks like that I may need to programmatically set the zoom-in scale of somehow(I am not sure whether this is possible without the gesture) in the

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // Perform the animation
    }
```

when I implement the the protocol `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` as mentioned in Mathew's blog http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/

Am I heading to the right direction? Can anyone have any idea about how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the right path. In the transition method, take the frame of the original block. Get a snapshot of the view you're transitioning to, and add it to the view at the frame. Then animate its size change to fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks. What did you mean by the frame of the original block. Can you clarify it a bit.

Comment: The frame of whatever view is tapped that you want to expand. Essentially you'll add a new view right on top of it so it looks like it expands.

Comment: See whether I understood it right. let's say I click specific news,which is the frame I want to capture a snapshot. Add the snap shot to the top the current view(let's say a list of news). then resize the snap shot?

Comment: Yes except you may also want to cross fade the snapshot from a snapshot of the news item to a snapshot of the full view that you will end with